# AndroidStudio team foundation server

Tags: android, tfs, android-studio

I've been using AndroidStudio from its release date and a part from all it's 
bugs i like it. I wanted to ask if anyone knows a way to share my project with 
my team to work on in AndroidStudio. Something like TFS for eclipse. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this discussion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/C_Gc6hVkig0

We just have to wait for the version 1.0 that should come in december.

**UPDATE**

From the [IntelliJ IDEA faq page:](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/)

> If I rely on features that are only available in IntelliJ IDEA
>   Ultimate (such as additional version control plugins), will I be able
>   to use Android Studio?
>
> No, these additional features will not be available in Android Studio.
>   You should continue using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Fortunately, all the Android Studio features can be found on IntelliJ IDEA as well.

Comment: So, we need to wait for a long time. Because Android is 0.3.1 by now.

Comment: yeah, i looked it up already. I hope, we 'll have this feature in android studio soon.